# jquery ajax procedure: How to hand over a parameter from function() to ajaxStart()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I got a simple jquery ajax procedure as shown below:

*html structure*

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head></head>

  <body>

    <div class="content"></div>

    <a onclick="ajaxCall('url.php', '.content')">load</a>

    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

*script.js*

```
function ajaxCall(request_url, target) {
  $.get(request_url, function(data) {
    $(target).html(data);
  });
}

$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
  $('.content').animate({opacity: '0.0'});
});

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $('.content').animate({opacity: '1.0'});
});
```

Is it possible to hand over the parameter "target" from function ajaxCall() to ajaxStart() and  ajaxSuccess()?

Comment: Where are `ajaxStart` and `ajaxSuccess` called?

Comment: Reload question .. I edit for precision

Comment: Create a global variable and when ajaxcall, set value of that variable = target, I think

Comment: thanks - working with a global var did it - hope this is kind of a nice way how to handle ajax requests ... or any concerns?

Comment: I usually use $.ajax({}) to handle ajax request. All in one then I dont need global variable. But with me, make it work is the first step :D